Speed-up literal_eval in a DataFrame apply
I have a pandas DataFrame with the following columns:
id | value        | somedate
------------------------------
1  | [10, 13, 14] | 2024-06-01
2  | [5, 6, 7]    | 2024-07-01
3  | [1, 2, 3]    | 2024-06-01

I'm doing the following transformation to parse the value column and explode the DataFrame:
import ast
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3], "value": ["[10, 13, 14]", "[5, 6, 7]", "[1, 2, 3]"], "somedate": ["2024-06-01", "2024-07-01", "2024-06-01"]})
data["parsed_value"] = data["value"].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
data = data.explode(column="parsed_value")

This works well on small DataFrames, but becomes incredibly slow at very large DataFrames (tens to hundreds of millions of rows).
Obviously, there are options like parallel processing, switching to other packages like dask or polars, but I just wanted to first make sure that I'm not missing some obvious solution within the current tech stack.

Another possible solution, using json.loads, which converts the string lists to lists:
import json 

data.assign(parsed_value = data.value.map(json.loads)).explode('parsed_value')

Output:
   id         value    somedate parsed_value
0   1  [10, 13, 14]  2024-06-01           10
0   1  [10, 13, 14]  2024-06-01           13
0   1  [10, 13, 14]  2024-06-01           14
1   2     [5, 6, 7]  2024-07-01            5
1   2     [5, 6, 7]  2024-07-01            6
1   2     [5, 6, 7]  2024-07-01            7
2   3     [1, 2, 3]  2024-06-01            1
2   3     [1, 2, 3]  2024-06-01            2
2   3     [1, 2, 3]  2024-06-01            3


Thanks! This actually executes in about 4 seconds on my dataset of ~10MM rows, which is perfect!

Welcome, @abudis!

If you make the assumption that the lists are valid and always represent lists of integers, you could use a regex with str.extractall, then join:
out = data.join(data['value'].str.extractall(r'(\d+)')[0]
                             .astype(int)
                             .droplevel('match').rename('parsed_value'))

Output:
   id         value    somedate parsed_value
0   1  [10, 13, 14]  2024-06-01           10
0   1  [10, 13, 14]  2024-06-01           13
0   1  [10, 13, 14]  2024-06-01           14
1   2     [5, 6, 7]  2024-07-01            5
1   2     [5, 6, 7]  2024-07-01            6
1   2     [5, 6, 7]  2024-07-01            7
2   3     [1, 2, 3]  2024-06-01            1
2   3     [1, 2, 3]  2024-06-01            2
2   3     [1, 2, 3]  2024-06-01            3

timings
It's almost 2 times faster for DataFrames of 1000+ rows:


I tried this solution, which executes in about 20 seconds on my dataset of about 10MM rows. However, I noticed that it produces an incorrect number of rows, when exploded. I think the assumption that the lists only contain integers is not holding, as some values are probably floats. Thank you anyway for this answer!
